# Filter an object on the basis of property inside nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have a javascript object structured like this:

```
var obj = {
    HEALTH: {
       business: "HEALTH",
       percentage: 0,
       outerCriteria:{
          DEFAULT:[
            {
                thePercentage : 10,
                innerCriteria : {
                     min: '10',
                     max: '20',
                     city: 'Denver',
               }
            }
          ],
          RANDOM:[
            {
                thePercentage : 20,
                innerCriteria : {
                     min: '50',
                     max: '20',
                     city: 'Darlington',
               }
            },
            {
                thePercentage : 30,
                innerCriteria : {
                     min: '50',
                     max: '60',
                     city: 'Barrington',
               }
            },
            {
                thePercentage : 36,
                innerCriteria : {
                     min: '20',
                     max: '62',
                     city: 'Barrington',
               }
            },
          ],
          NEW:[
            {
                thePercentage : 5,
                innerCriteria : {
                     min: '5',
                     max: '20',
                     city: 'Darlington',
               }
            },
            {
                thePercentage : 6,
                innerCriteria : {
                     min: '5',
                     max: '60',
                     city: 'Darlington',
               }
            },
            {
                thePercentage : 36,
                innerCriteria : {
                     min: '20',
                     max: '62',
                     city: 'Barrington',
               }
            },
          ],
       }
    } 
}
```

I want this to be filtered on the basis of *city*. For example, if I filter for *Darlington*, desired output would be:

```
var obj = {
    HEALTH: {
       business: "HEALTH",
       percentage: 0,
       outerCriteria:{
          RANDOM:[
            {
                thePercentage : 20,
                innerCriteria : {
                     min: '50',
                     max: '20',
                     city: 'Darlington',
               }
            },
          ],
          NEW:[
            {
                thePercentage : 5,
                innerCriteria : {
                     min: '5',
                     max: '20',
                     city: 'Darlington',
               }
            },
            {
                thePercentage : 6,
                innerCriteria : {
                     min: '5',
                     max: '60',
                     city: 'Darlington',
               }
            },
          ],
       }
    } 
}
```

I tried using filter and map but of no use. I tries filter with some but was not able to get it through.

Stack overflow is not letting me post this question saying to give more details. I don't have more details man. This is all i have. If anyone wants to ask you can always comment.

Please Help.
Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `array.filter()` method to filter by city and the `delete()` method to delete object properties (if the array associated with the given key is empty).

Example function:

```
function filterByCity(city) {
    for(let o in obj.HEALTH.outerCriteria) {
        obj.HEALTH.outerCriteria[o] = obj.HEALTH.outerCriteria[o].filter((item) => item.innerCriteria.city == city);
        if(obj.HEALTH.outerCriteria[o].length == 0) {  // if the array is empty delete it
            delete(obj.HEALTH.outerCriteria[o]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Run and test:**

```js
var obj = {
    HEALTH: {
       business: "HEALTH",
       percentage: 0,
       outerCriteria:{
          DEFAULT:[
            {
                thePercentage : 10,
                innerCriteria : {
                     min: '10',
                     max: '20',
                     city: 'Denver',
               }
            }
          ],
          RANDOM:[
            {
                thePercentage : 20,
                innerCriteria : {
                     min: '50',
                     max: '20',
                     city: 'Darlington',
               }
            },
            {
                thePercentage : 30,
                innerCriteria : {
                     min: '50',
                     max: '60',
                     city: 'Barrington',
               }
            },
            {
                thePercentage : 36,
                innerCriteria : {
                     min: '20',
                     max: '62',
                     city: 'Barrington',
               }
            },
          ],
          NEW:[
            {
                thePercentage : 5,
                innerCriteria : {
                     min: '5',
                     max: '20',
                     city: 'Darlington',
               }
            },
            {
                thePercentage : 6,
                innerCriteria : {
                     min: '5',
                     max: '60',
                     city: 'Darlington',
               }
            },
            {
                thePercentage : 36,
                innerCriteria : {
                     min: '20',
                     max: '62',
                     city: 'Barrington',
               }
            },
          ],
       }
    } 
}

function filterByCity(city) {
  for(let o in obj.HEALTH.outerCriteria) {
    obj.HEALTH.outerCriteria[o] = obj.HEALTH.outerCriteria[o].filter((item) => item.innerCriteria.city == city);
    if(obj.HEALTH.outerCriteria[o].length == 0) {  // if the array is empty delete it
      delete(obj.HEALTH.outerCriteria[o]);
    }
  }
}

filterByCity('Darlington');
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var unfilteredOuterCriteria = obj.HEALTH.outerCriteria;
var filteredOuterCriteria = {};

for(attr in obj.HEALTH.outerCriteria){
    filteredOuterCriteria[attr] = 
obj.HEALTH.outerCriteria[attr].filter(criteria => criteria.innerCriteria.city === 'Darlington');
}

obj.HEALTH.outerCriteria = filteredOuterCriteria;
```

Comment: And how is this different from my example? You practically re-posted the same answer...